# Ruby - HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) within inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, associations

I am having trouble associating these models together.

```
class LongTermFinanceScorecard < Scorecard
  has_one :access_to_finance, foreign_key: :scorecard_id
  has_one :insurance_policy, through: :access_to_finance, class_name: 'LongTermAccessToFinance'
end

class AccessToFinance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scorecard
end

class LongTermAccessToFinance < AccessToFinance
  has_one :insurance_policy, foreign_key: 'access_to_finance_id'
end

class InsurancePolicy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :access_to_finance, class_name: 'LongTermAccessToFinance'
  belongs_to :scorecard
end

class LongTermInsurancePolicy < InsurancePolicy
end
```

So when a `LongTermFinanceScorecard` is created, it builds a `LongTermAccessToFinance` which builds a `LongTermInsurancePolicy`.

`LongTermAccessToFinance` inherits from `AccessToFinance` and `LongTermInsurancePolicy` inherits from `InsurancePolicy` respectively.

If i run this is in the rails console i get the following results.

```
s = LongTermFinanceScorecard.create
  => true
s.access_to_finance
  => true
s.access_to_finance.insurance_policy
  => true
i = s.access_to_finance.insurance_policy
  => true
i.scorecard == s
  => true #This shows that the relationship works backwards
s.insurance_policy
  => ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :insurance_policy or :insurance_policy in model AccessToFinance. Try 'has_many :insurance_policy, :through => :access_to_finance, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :scorecard
```

The `Could not find the source association(s) :insurance_policy or :insurance_policy in model AccessToFinance.` part of the error suggests that its looking for insurance_policy in `AccessToFinance` when its actually belongs to `LongTermAccessToFinance`.

How do i reference the type of `AccessToFinance` Object within the association?

**EDIT**

From the Ruby on Rails API i find this under the options for the has_one: association

```
:class_name
   Specify the class name of the association. Use it only if that name can't be inferred from the association name. So has_one :manager will by default be linked to the Manager class, but if the real class name is Person, you'll have to specify it with this option.

:through
  Specifies a Join Model through which to perform the query. Options for :class_name, :primary_key, and :foreign_key are ignored, as the association uses the source reflection. You can only use a :through query through a has_one or belongs_to association on the join model.

:source
  Specifies the source association name used by has_one :through queries. Only use it if the name cannot be inferred from the association. has_one :favorite, through: :favorites will look for a :favorite on Favorite, unless a :source is given.

:source_type
  Specifies type of the source association used by has_one :through queries where the source association is a polymorphic belongs_to.
```

So it would seem as if `class_name:` is not working because its still looking for associations from `AccessToFinance` and not `LongTermAccessToFinance`

Comment: `AccessToFinance` missing one `has_one` association.. Look at the model, nothing is there.. whereas you have `belongs_to` inside the `InsurancePolicy` model. :)

Comment: @ArupRakshit but thats the thing. `InsurancePolicy` dose not belong to `AccessToFinance`, it belongs to `LongTermAccessToFinance`, so it should not have a relationship.

Comment: Ill amend the code to reflect the `class_name:` but i have tested it with the `class_name:` defined and i get the same result

Comment: Your error message is telling what it is looking for *Could not find the source association(s) :insurance_policy or :insurance_policy in model AccessToFinance.* That's the best hint. Rest need a console and data to try ... and fix. :)